# Iterating over a list stored in webElement

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, appium, python-appium

I am learning appium (mobile automation) using python.

I have a scenario where I have a listView and I have to iterate through each item and then click back until all items are clicked.

I am using following code:

```
def test_selectingEveryOption(self):
        availableOptions = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//android.widget.ListView')
        for options in availableOptions:
            availableOptions[options].click()
            self.driver.back()
```

availableOptions is the webElement that have the list. When I run above piece of code, I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement`

Since availableOptions is webElement, how can I get its list items as integers and then iterate over them?

Comment: Is availableOptions list?

Comment: No, availableOptions is a list of WebElement objects, `find_elements_by_xpath` always returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

`browser.find_elements_by_class_name("myClass")` returns a list of WebElements. So.. in your for-loop, each iteration produces a WebElement, not an integer index... you don't need to use indexes at all.

```
for element in self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//android.widget.ListView'):
    element_contents = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: But I'm getting noSuchElementException for the list..

NoSuchElementException: Message: This element does not have the 'innerHTML' attribute

Comment: I'm not very well versed with python-appium but how about you find out you print all the attributes associated with 'element' inside the loop and see which one suits your needsm